# How to shift the position of the group bar chart?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I extract the following code from the matlab official website, 'https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html':

```
x = [1980 1990 2000];
y = [40 50 63 52; 42 55 50 48; 30 20 44 40];
barh(x,y)
xlabel('Snowfall')
ylabel('Year')
legend({'Springfield','Fairview','Bristol','Jamesville'})
```

Currently, all the bars are plotted at level 0. I want that for the group 1980, say the 4 numbers [40,50,63,52] can be plotted at level 10; for the group 1990, the 4 numbers [42,55,50,48] can be plotted at the 20 and for the group 2000, the 4 numbers [30,20,44,40] can be plotted at the level 0. How can I do it?

Comment: But that would not be a valid bar char anymore right?

Comment: logically you are correct, but I need to plot this kind of graph.

Comment: Then maybe use patch() or rectangle() and control where you draw them